# Does windows 7 come with Silverlight preinstalled on a standard end- user system?

Tags: windows-7, silverlight

I am asking as Windows 7 laptops (at least from dell) seem to come with Flash preinstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is.

[Source](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/135813/303322.aspx)

Flash isn't pre-installed either. It's something that Dell do for you, along with all the other applications they install.

At some point they might include Silverlight, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know - Silverlight is not bundled with Windows 7.